# Missing expected identifier

Tags: iphone

Getting message `expected identifier` in red for below these two statements

```
}  else if ([playpauseButton.state == UIControlStateSelected])

} else if ([playpauseButton.state == UIControlStateNormal])
```

I m not getting where i m missing identifier in below play/pause/resumeaction

```
if( playpauseButton.state == UIControlStateNormal ){
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[audioPlayer play];
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:NO];

}  else if ([playpauseButton.state == UIControlStateSelected])
{
[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[audioPlayer pause];
[self pauseTimer];
} else if ([playpauseButton.state == UIControlStateNormal])
{
[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[audioPlayer play];
[self resumeTimer];}}
```

I have programmed this way because i want when play is pressed it should play audio file plus start `NSTimer` to load `view controllers` one after another. When pause is pressed it should pause audio file plus `NSTimer` to avoid further loading of `view controllers` one after another and finally pause is resumed back to play audio file from the same point it should resume timer to start loading `view controllers` one after the other from that point.

If any one can help me to solve this.

Appreciate help.

Thanks.

Comment: wich line do you recieve that? what are those messages?

Comment: why do you have two conditions checking same thing in if and else if{} `if( playpauseButton.state == UIControlStateNormal )`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put square brackets around your conditional tests.  The syntax is just `else if (playpauseButton.state == UIControlStateSelected)`.